# Getting URLs of webpage excluding the URLs of the components

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the URLs of all the webpages on the first page of google search results using javascript excluding the URLs of components on the search page i.e. twitter component, video component, people also ask component etc. But i don't know how to exclude those URLs? I have tried getting them by using following code

```
for (url in urls) {
  var a = urls[url].href;
  var aURL1 = urls[url].href;
  console.log(aURL1);
  console.log(a);
  if (urls[url].textContent == aURL1) {
    console.log("found");
  }
}
```

but it is giving all the URLs including the URLs from video, twitter etc components.

Comment: where is the code? please update question with code.

Comment: Can you provide what `urls` will contain?

Comment: var urls = document.getElementsByClassName('iUh30 bc');  it will contain the elements of the class on search page

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.
You can actually get all the url's using `document.querySelectorAll('a')` and filter twitter and video links (Shown below)

```
const excludeUrls = ['twitter', 'youtube'];
const allUrls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(each => each.href);
const finalUrls = [];
for (const each of allUrls) {
    let cnt = 0;
    for(const elm of excludeUrls) {
        if (each.includes(elm)) cnt++
    }
    if (!cnt) {
     finalUrls.push(each);
    }
}
console.log('All Urls Count: ' + allUrls.length, 'Filtered Urls Count: ' + finalUrls.length);
console.log(finalUrls);
```

**I would like to ask one question, what's the use case ?, why are you doing this ?**

Comment: Thats great. What about the URLs in the component of People also ask? How can we exclude those URLs? 
I am using it for some kind of data collection for research purposes.

Comment: @SecurityGeek I am not aware of component, can you please tell me what is twitter component and  video component ?, What is it ?

Comment: I've posted the screenshot below.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
@SameerKhan this is the component on a search page. When searching for something, this appears on the search result page. How can we exclude the URLs it contains and just get the main URLs of page?

Comment: How are you executing the code, I hope you are executing by opening dev tools of that search page, If so then before executing just inspect that block and delete it, this way you only get what you want

Comment: querying with `document.getElementsByClassName` is a bad idea, cauz in future classes will be changed or some of the links will not be queried (if that doesn't have the same class)

Comment: Can we do this inspect and delete thing with the code in javascript? That everytime when extension executes, it automatically inspects and delete that?

Comment: You can remove/delete element with programmatically by querying element and invoking `.remove()` function, but as I said, you can't select the element with classes(It may change in future)